# Switch from RVM to rbenv passenger preload/bundle errors on app start RubyVersionMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, rbenv

It looks like the Phusion Passenger preloader or bundler is calling the system version of kernel_require.rb rather than the rbenv version of kernel_require.rb and bundler complains about `RubyVersionMismatch` when I startup my Rails 4.1 application. This is my local dev box but I also have a "local" environment for deployment using Apache 2.2.27 (macports).

I completely removed RVM per the instructions, installed rbenv per the instructions then installed Ruby 2.1.2, Rails 4.1.5, Passenger, and did `passenger-install-apache2-module`.  All these were done in my deploy account then I created a blank testing application. When the application starts up the Apache error log reports `Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch`.

Note that the application seems to work just fine.

log lines referencing rbenv ruby:

```
log:1 /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:385:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
log:2 /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
log:3 /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

log lines referencing mac system ruby:

```
log:4 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/.../ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/.../kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
log:5 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/.../ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/.../kernel_require.rb:55 in `require'
log:6 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298: Preloader for /path/to/my/deploy/rails/testing/current started on PID 33863
```

Environment:

```
OSX 10.9.4
Apache 2.2.27 installed via macports to /opt/local/apache2 etc
rbenv local 2.1.2  
rbenv global 2.1.2
rbenv which ruby /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
rbenv whence passenger 2.1.2
rails -v 4.1.5
bundler version 1.7.2
using mina v0.3.0, mina-rsync for deploy
```

Passenger config for apache:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.50
PassengerDefaultRuby /path/to/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not set `rbenv local` or `global` in the deploy account.

- fix and clean:  probably overkill
- removed rbenv from deploy account:

  ```
  rm -rf ~/.rbenv
  ```
- removed rbenv setup from .bash_profile
- install rbenv per instructions:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
  echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  $ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- logout/login
- add rbenv setup to .bash_profile
- install rbenv-build:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
  ```
- install Ruby 2.1.2 and Bundler:

  ```
  rbenv install 2.1.2 
  gem install bundler
  ```
- set `rbenv global`:

  ```
  rbenv global 2.1.2
  gem install passenger 
  passenger-install-apache2-module
  ```
- copy suggested passenger config to my local /path/do/apache2/conf.d/passenger.conf
- `sudo apachectl restart`
- remove testing app from local staging server:

  ```
  rm -rf /path/to/my/deploy/testing/*
  ```

Returning back to the development account:

- recreate testing app

  ```
  rails new .... testing
  ```
- cd testing

  ```
  rake db:create  
  rake db:migrate
  git init
  git add .
  git commit -am 'initial'
  git push origin master

  mina -v setup server=local
  mina -v deploy server=local
  ```
- `tail -f /path/to/apache2/logs/error_log`

I hit my app on my local server and `RubyVersionMismatch` is no longer in the error log, and the application starts normally.

Comment: skipped a couple of rbenv rehash statements in my explanation  after gem install bundler and gem install passenger

Comment: Could the problem caused by forgetting to change `passenger_ruby` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?